# How can ffmpeg scale videos to the same size, preserving their aspect ratio?

Tags: ffmpeg

(I have searched similar questions and haven't found anything that works the way I describe here.)

I have a number of videos of varying sample and display aspect ratios(and different framerates and timebases). I want to concatenate them into one long video, like a playlist, which means re-encoding them. I want them to scale up or down to fit within the desired output size (768x432), preserving their aspect ratio by pillarboxing when necessary.

I've tried `-vf scale=768:432:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=768:432:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2`, which produces a 768x432 16:9 video from a 16:9 input... but squishes it vertically and adds pillarboxing anyway. (The input is 720x480 with a 32:27 sample aspect ratio. Input of a 10:11 SAR, 4:3 DAR 704x480 video works.)

Answer (score 0):

The scale filter does not adjust for the SAR of the input. You'll have to use expressions for this:

```
scale='if(gt(dar\,768/432),768,oh*dar)':'if(gt(dar\,768/432),ow/dar,432)',setsar=1,pad=...
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can recall of my own testing this should work for both 16:9 and non-16:9 video, i think the syntax and order of the setsar function does impact the result

`-filter_complex "scale=768:432:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,setsar=sar=1,pad=768:432:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2"`

If that works and you want to convert in as high a quality as possible the I'd suggest you try `-filter_complex "scale=768:432:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:flags=lanczos+full_chroma_int+accurate_rnd,scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2,setsar=sar=1,pad=768:432:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2"`